# Select field that is created on the fly

Tags: php, mysql

Assume a table bank contains 3 fields, id, name, and balance.

I am trying to understand how to select all fields from this table and add another custom field to the result set as follows:

Query (something like)

```
SELECT * FROM bank WHERE balance+10 AS plusTen AND id != 12
```

PHP

```
echo $row['plusTen']; //echos whatever balance was for this record + 10 added to it
```

Is this even possible?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `SELECT 'foo' as myData; echo $row['myData'];` You can alias fields and select them in php

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, balance+10 AS plusTen
FROM ...
etc...
```

you can create virtual fields in a WHERE clause, if you insist, but things in `where` clauses don't get returned to the client, because they simply act as filters. You need to actually create the virtual field in the field portion of the query, as above.

Comment: How would one select `FROM id=10`?

Comment: You really need to learn basic SQL syntax. You're randomly rewriting the syntax to try and suit YOUR needs. No, you can't do it that way. you can do nested queries as a subselect, e.g. `SELECT foo+10 FROM (select ...))`.

Comment: +1, @Mike B, I apologize I had a typo. Thanks for the reply. The problem is, I would like to do something like `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id=10 AS tenthId` and create a 'new field' after the WHERE has been applied, is this possible?

Comment: `SELECT *, 10 tenthID FROM someTable WHERE id=10`

Comment: where is applied at the row level anyways. just put the +10 into your field list and there where will filter out any records that shouldnt' get included to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the additional field in the `SELECT` not the `WHERE` part of the statment, like so:

```
SELECT *,
    balance+10 AS plusTen
FROM bank
WHERE id != 12
```

***To add more fields, just separate them with a comma after the `SELECT` part of the statement***